# using rstudio on r 3.0.1

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently installed R 3.0.1 and cannot find a way to use Rstudio. When I click on a data frame it calls for me to re-install 'rstudio.' However when I try to install using:

```
install.packages('rstudio')
```

I get the following error message

```
package ‘rstudio’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I've also tried to go to Tools>Options>General and change the R program to R.3.0.1.

I am using Windows 7 and would love to continue Rstudio for the user interface. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you try searching for "Rstudio installation"?

Comment: try unchecking the "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP" in Tools->Options->Packages.  This might be a "Spybot-Search and Destroy" issue?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the way to install R Studio is to go to their [site](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/).